# Load excel sheet into oracle db through forms 6i

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

i got a link which has this code to load excel data to a db table through oracle forms ,

```
DECLARE   
 application OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;   
 workbooks OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;   
 workbook OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;   
 worksheets OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;   
 worksheet OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;   
 cell OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;   
 args OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;   
 ctr NUMBER(12);   
 cols NUMBER(2);  
 name_var1 VARCHAR2(2000);   
 name_var2 VARCHAR2(2000);   
 name_var3 VARCHAR2(2000);   
 name_var4 VARCHAR2(2000);   
 filename varchar2(100);  

 PROCEDURE OLEARG IS  
 args OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;   
 BEGIN  
 args := OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;   
 ole2.add_arg(args,ctr); -- row value  
 ole2.add_arg(args,cols); -- column value  
 cell := ole2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(worksheet,'Cells',args); -- initializing cell  
 ole2.destroy_arglist(args);   
 END;  

 BEGIN  
 filename :=GET_FILE_NAME('c:\', File_Filter=>'Excel Files (*.xls)|*.xls|'); -- to pick the file  
 application := OLE2.CREATE_OBJ('Excel.Application');   
 ole2.set_property(application,'Visible','true');   
 workbooks := OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(application, 'Workbooks');   
 args := OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;   
 ole2.add_arg(args,filename); --'c:\13s002.xls'); -- file path and name  
 workbook := ole2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(workbooks,'Open',args);   
 ole2.destroy_arglist(args);   
 args := OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;   
 ole2.add_arg(args,'Sheet1');   
 worksheet := ole2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(workbook,'Worksheets',args);   
 ole2.destroy_arglist(args);   

 ctr := 2; --row number  
 cols := 1; -- column number  

 FIRST_RECORD;   

 LOOP   
 OLEARG;  
 name_var1 := ole2.get_char_property(cell,'Value'); --cell value of the argument  
 cols := cols+1;  

 OLEARG;  
 name_var2 := ole2.get_char_property(cell,'Value'); --cell value of the argument  
 cols := cols+1;  

 OLEARG;  
 name_var3 := ole2.get_char_property(cell,'Value'); --cell value of the argument  
 cols := cols+1;  

 OLEARG;  
 name_var4 := ole2.get_num_property(cell,'Value'); --cell number value of the argument  

 IF ctr = 1 then   
 :tf1 := name_var1;   
 :tf2 := name_var2;   
 :tf3 := name_var3;   
 :tf4 := name_var4;   
 ELSE   
 NEXT_RECORD;   
 :tf1 := name_var1;   
 :tf2 := name_var2;   
 :tf3 := name_var3;   
 :tf4 := name_var4;  
 END IF;   

 EXIT WHEN length(name_var1) = 0 or length(name_var1) is null;   
 ctr := ctr + 1;   
 cols := 1;  

 END LOOP;   
 OLE2.INVOKE(application,'Quit');   
 OLE2.RELEASE_OBJ(cell);   
 OLE2.RELEASE_OBJ(worksheet);   
 OLE2.RELEASE_OBJ(worksheets);   
 OLE2.RELEASE_OBJ(workbook);   
 OLE2.RELEASE_OBJ(workbooks);   
 OLE2.RELEASE_OBJ(application);   
 END;
```

i have oracle forms 6i 
the problem is there are some arguments which i should replace with values , and i do not know which arguments should i replace with values ? could you please tell me ?

-- i created 4 text-items (:tf1 , :tf2 , :tf3 , :tf4).
-- i have a .xls file called "employees" on the partition "d:\" .
--these lines

```
name_var1 := ole2.get_char_property(cell,'Value'); --cell value of the argument 
cols := cols+1;
OLEARG;
name_var2 := ole2.get_char_property(cell,'Value'); --cell value of the argument 
cols := cols+1;
OLEARG;
name_var3 := ole2.get_char_property(cell,'Value'); --cell value of the argument 
cols := cols+1;
OLEARG;
name_var4 := ole2.get_num_property(cell,'Value'); --cell number value of the argument  ,
```

i think the "Value" argument should be replaced with something , but i do not what is it ? and what is the meaning of "cell value of the argument" and

"cell number value of the argument"

?

Comment: I've responded to your [OTN thread](https://community.oracle.com/message/12589849)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to find more information about this class. It looks like `'Value'` is the data you want back from the cell: value or formula.  `OLEARG;` is an in-line procedure that has to be the last definition in your opening block. cols is used to walk through each column and ctr is used to walk through the rows of the xls file.  `OLEARG;` is expecting these variable names to exist in your code. If you have more columns then you need to have a set of these three statements for each additional column

`OLEARG;
 name_var3 := ole2.get_char_property(cell,'Value');
 cols := cols+1;`

You do realize that you will have to remove all this code when you migrate to another version of forms above 6i?